# In angular, how to dynamically add different FormGroup into a FormArray?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I want to dynamically add several dishes into this order array. Each dish is a FormGroup.  Dish could be pizza, salad, drink or something else. Before adding anything, the form should look this:

```
this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: [''],
  order: this.fb.array([])
});
```

After added dishes, form should be something like this:

```
this.fb.group({
 firstName: ['', Validators.required],
 lastName: [''],
 order: this.fb.array([
   {type:pizza, name:summerPizza, size:8},
   {type:salad, name:goodsalad, size:small},
   {type:pizza, name:nicePizza, size:11},
   {type:drink, name:beer, brand:abc},
 ])
});
```

User can add as many items as they want. So how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly, you would likely want a method that returns a `formGroup` you want to add to the `formArray`.

Making the assumption this is within a component class context.

in .ts:

```
formGroup = this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: [''],
  order: this.fb.array([])
});
```

```
createOrder(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    type: this.fb.control(""),
    name: this.fb.control(""),
    size: this.fb.control(""),
    brand: this.fb.control(""),
  });
}
```

then you'd have a method that would call that `createOrder` and add the `formGroup` to the `formArray`

```
get ordersFormArray(): FormArray {
 return this.formGroup.get('orders') as FormArray;
}
```

```
addOrder() {
  this.ordersFromArray.push(this.createOrder())
}
```